# Get Intent action only if the app is wasn't launched

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I currently have this code... :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.VIEW")) {
        String filename = intent.getData().getPath();
        file = new File(filename);
    } else {
        file = new File(sdcard, "myfile.txt");
    }
}
```

...which works only on the app startup (when launched from the launcher or from a file explorer).

My problem is that I'm using **another activity** with a back button in the action bar.
When we go back to the MainActivity, it recalls the `OnCreate` method and at this moment, there is an error with `intent.getAction()`.

I guess the action string is null because the error is :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : java.lang.NullPointerException`

So my question is the next : *How can I prevent my MainActivity to call the `intent.getAction()` method when the user has pressed Second Activity's back button ?*

PS : I don't need this method to be called twice ;)

Comment: can't you just check `if intent.getAction() != null &&` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Perfect, thank you !